# Function doesn't do anything when called from a parent component's event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this simplified react components structure:

```
<Content>
    <Activity>
        <EditableDiv>
        </EditableDiv>
    </Activity>
</Content>
```

Inside `<EditableDiv>`, I want to call a function inside `<EditableDiv>` whenever the first ancestor gets scrolled. In this case, a div inside `<Content>` is that first ancestor so I register a function to be called on its `onscroll` event.

```
function EditableDiv(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
    const [showActionButtons, setShowActionButtons] = useState({ shown: true });

    useEffect(init, []);

    function init() {
        const el = document.getElementById("main-container");
        if (el !== null) {
            const scrollParent = UiHelper.getScrollParent(el);
            scrollParent.onscroll = function () {
                closeActionButtons();
            };
        }
    }
    
    function closeActionButtons() {
        setShowActionButtons({ shown: false });
    }

    return (
        <div id="main-container">
        </div>
    );
}
```

Function `closeActionButtons` gets called (breakpoint is hit) but it seems to do nothing when it should hide some buttons. I tried registering an `onclick` handler now inside the `<EditableDiv>` component and calling the same `closeActionButtons` function and the hiding successfully happens.

It seems it just doesn't work inside that function registered to the `onscroll` event of a parent component. Furthermore, in my `setValue`, you can see I passed `props.value` (which has some string values). When I put a breakpoint inside the `onscroll` function the `props.value` is undefined but inside the `onclick` function, that original value that I passed is retained.

Comment: useEffect only run once, when this component gets mounted.
You need to pass in the second argument, so whenever that changes the effect will run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure I understand. I only need the init to be called once, to register an onscroll event handler, which currently is happening. When I scroll, the closeActionButtons gets called but it seems the line setShowActionButtons({ shown: false }); doesn't update the value.

Comment: It's scope is only in that component, so if that component somehow gets unmounted that value will not be retained

Comment: It's not good practice to use `document.getElementById()` in React though. React has its own methods to reference the DOM. Apart from that, is the `main-container` part of a React component? If so, you could use `<div onScroll={}>` in that component to listen for scroll events. You could then pass the scroll handler down as a prop to the child component if you want. (In React you don't search "up" for parent components, but instead you pass things "down", the hierarchy goes from top to bottom).

Answer (score 0):

## `useRef`

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```js
function EditableDiv(props) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  const [showActionButtons, setShowActionButtons] = useState({
    shown: true
  });

  useEffect(init, []);

  function init() {
    const el = containerRef.current;
    if (el !== null) {
      const scrollParent = UiHelper.getScrollParent(el);
      scrollParent.onscroll = function() {
        closeActionButtons();
      };
    }
  }

  function closeActionButtons() {
    setShowActionButtons({
      shown: false
    });
  }

  return ( <div ref={containerRef} ></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this one out, copied exactly what you posted up to closeActionButtons and then added the ref={containerRef} in my div but it still behaves the same as before.